# How to set segue doing pop to root and push a new one in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xib

I want to make a segue that makes navigation controller poptoroot and then make a new controller pushed into the navigation controller .
e.g Now the controller hierarchy is

```
 navigationController->rootcontroller->controllerA ->controllerB
```

and i want to make a segue perfome in controller B,and the segue will make the hierarchy to

```
navigationController->rootcontroller-> controllerC
```

is this possible?

Comment: clarify your requirements more.

Comment: @vaibhav i have edit my question , can you get my question now ?

Comment: if the rootView is embed with navigationCont you can perform segue to any vc.

Comment: you mean i can  do these two steps 1) pop to root 2) push a controller in one segue? how to set ?

Comment: confused, how you can perform these two actions at a time.

Comment: Using storyboard only will be really difficult (To not say impossible) to achieve. If you are open to do programmatically check the `setViewControllers(viewControllers:animated:)` in UINavigationController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set segue doing pop to root. This can be achieved using `Unwind Segues`. For more detail regarding this you can follow this `Apple` doc.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013591-CH1-TNTAG2-ADDING_AN_UNWIND_SEGUE_TO_A_STORYBOARD

For pushing to new VC, You can simply push in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to pop till root or where you want and use same method to push forward:

```
// For Pop

     NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
        for( int i=0;i<[viewControllers count];i++){
            id obj=[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
            if([obj isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerYouWantToStopOn class]]){
                [[self navigationController] popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
                return;
            }
        }

//For Push

 NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
        for( int i=0;i<[viewControllers count];i++){
            id obj=[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
            if([obj isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerYouWantToJumpOn class]]){
                [[self navigationController] pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: bacause now i was using the storyboard , and i want to do this kind of transition in storyboard way , thanks @Vinnet Rai

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me :

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_id", sender: self)
var navigationArray = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
var i = navigationArray!.count - 2
while i > 0 {
    navigationArray!.remove(at: i)
    i = i - 1
}
self.navigationController?.viewControllers = navigationArray!
```

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.